# Swift bug? calling super class method when subclass with generic type

Tags: swift

Not very sure if this is my problem of swift. But I already submitted a bug.
Please take a look at the attached, the last line shall show 'hola', but it shows 'hello'.

[image]

It's blocking my project, anyway to walk around? Thanks.

// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

```
import UIKit

protocol Hello {
    class func hello() -> String
}

class HelloEnglish: Hello {
    class func hello() -> String {
        return "hello"
    }
}

class HelloSpanish<E>: HelloEnglish {
    override class func hello() -> String {
        return "hola"
    }
}

typealias HelloSpanishClass = HelloSpanish<AnyObject>

println("expect: hello")
HelloEnglish.hello()
println("expect: hola")
HelloSpanishClass.hello()

func sayHello<T: Hello>(type: T.Type) -> String {
    return type.hello()
}

println("expect: hello")
sayHello(HelloEnglish.self)
println("expect: hola")
sayHello(HelloSpanishClass.self)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with Xcode 6.1.

Comment: is your xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)? I paste the code, can u try again? THanks.

Comment: Forget my last comment, I did not use your exact code (text is much better than a screenshot!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2006)

[image]

In the Release notes of 6.1.1 Apple mentions that this bug is fixed:

> Class methods and initializers that satisfy protocol requirements now properly invoke subclass overrides when called in generic contexts. (18828217) For example:
>
> ```
> protocol P {
>    class func foo()
>  }
>  class C: P {
>    class func foo() { println("C!") }
>  }
>  class D: C {
>    override class func foo() { println("D!") }
>  }
>  func foo<T: P>(x: T) {
>    x.dynamicType.foo()
>  }
>  foo(C()) // Prints "C!"
>  foo(D()) // Used to incorrectly print "C!", now prints "D!"
> ```

Comment: I still have this problem in xcode 6.2. My generic method is invoking the class method of it self and not the overrided one in the subclass :(

Comment: I am having the same problem. When using generics, the method in the super class is being called instead of the overridden method in the subclass. Feels like a bug? A pretty serious one