# Generic UITableViewController in Swift compiles but doesn't reload its data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, generics

So I read the [article](http://www.objc.io/snippets/21.html) over at [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/snippets/21.html) about functional TableViewControllers. Sounds and looks clean so I had to try.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewController<A>: UITableViewController {

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var data: [A] = [] {
        didSet { self.tableView.reloadData() }
    }

    var configureCell: (UITableViewCell, A) -> () = { _ in () }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        configureCell(cell, data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine. I initialize it i with the following code.

```
let controller = TableViewController<String>(style: .Plain)
controller.configureCell = { (cell:UITableViewCell, data:String) in 
    cell.textLabel?.text = data
}
controller.data = ["1", "2"]
```

But `numberOfRowsInSection` is never called (and therefor nor is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). `didSet { self.tableView.reloadData() }` is however called.

I also checked that `tableView` has its dataSource and delegate sat correctly.

So If I remove that `<A>` in the class declaration, and replaces all the others with `String`. It works perfectly.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in our sample code. Sorry about that. I'm the one to blame.

The problem is probably that you can't make a generic subclass of a non-generic class... Will push out a fix soon.

Comment: Hi, Chris. Check my answer in this post.

Comment: "Any" isn't masked as generic. 
Doesn't look pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not know how many sections you have.

You need to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` first. Once it knows how many sections it will ask for each sections rows.

Comment: I already tried that. Doesn't help. And as I described, by just removing the genericness of the class, it works. So its something else.

Comment: I take it it is a typo in your question that the class is defined as TableViewContorller<A> and not TableViewController<A>. Might be worth updating the code to exactly what you have now.

Comment: Are you on the latest xcode? Seems it was a bug in xcode 6.1. You need 6.1.1 or higher. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143992/swift-bug-calling-super-class-method-when-subclass-with-generic-type

Comment: Rory I am on Version 6.3 (6D543q). I also corrected the typo. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: It would seem the problem relates to the fact you are subclassing an Objective C class and that overriding from a generic subclass of an objective C class is not supported. What you can do is put in an intermediate. So create `TableViewControllerBridge` say which inherits as normal and implements the normal delegate methods. From there call new versions you provide like `myNumberOfSectionsInTableView:`. You can then subclass again using generics as you are doing in your code, but subclass `TableViewControllerBridge`. As swift is inheriting swift you should be able to override the new funcs.

Answer (score 0):

as Chris says, unfortunately swift doesn't support generic subclassing on non-generic.
By the way, I've realized bypass of similar needs:
https://github.com/dimpiax/FlexibleTableViewController

Answer (score -2):

You can try reloading the data using `viewWillAppear`. When the view appears it will reload the data and update the table. Try this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    YourTableName.reloadData();
}
```